# NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.sender returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, basic-authentication, nsurlsession

Forgive the dot notation in my question.

I'm using NSURLSession to try logging into a website. Apple's documentation suggest handling authentication challenges in such a manner.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
                                             completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"<email>"
                                                             password:@"<password>"
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

The problem is that [challenge sender] returns nil. Did I miss something in my setup?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, but you should call the completion handler in place of the older useCredential method:

```
   completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up going in a completely different direction. I suppose the responsible thing to do would be double back and record my response. I will try my best to do that this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to authorize using http header for session authorisation:

```
NSString *userPasswordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, password];
NSData * userPasswordData = [userPasswordString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64EncodedCredential = [userPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64EncodedCredential];

configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": authString};
```